# QUdpSocket setSockOpt

Tags: qt, udp, qudpsocket

I have some old code, which use this flags in socket:

```
unsigned char str_optval [8] = {0xfc, 0x08, 0xff, 0x33, 0xcc, 0xff, 0xaa, 0x0};
res=setsockopt(sid,SOL_IP,IP_OPTIONS, (char*)&str_optval,sizeof(str_optval));
```

How can I change this place to use QUdpSocket? I can't find any analog setsockopt in QUdpClass. QAbstractSocket provide setSocketOption, which allow only 4 variants flags (enum). I need it only in linux version, so if any native func it's ok.

Comment: You might have to just continue using `setsockopt`.  Just get the socket descriptor from the `QUdpSocket`.  Refer to `QAbstractSocket::socketDescriptor()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtnetwork/qabstractsocket.html#SocketOption-enum

Socket options are not limited to UDP datagrams. Having said that, Qt only has a limited number of options you can set on a socket. The most common options to actually being able to set. The rest are platform specific stuff.

ASIDE: hardcoded literals, like in your quoted code, are a big no-no. Non-portable and a nightmare to maintain. Whatever you do, at least change those literals to names defined in standard headers.

Comment: Aside: sure this is the reason why I start refactor. I don't know what means that hex consts ))

Comment: If this is for Linux, you can look at socket options in /usr/include/bits/in.h . It seems that the actual structure this represents is     struct ip_opts
      {
        struct in_addr ip_dst;      /* First hop; zero without source route.  */
        char ip_opts[40];           /* Actually variable in size.  */
      };
Good luck.